# Yammer support in Scribe

Tags: scribe, yammer

I'd like to use Scribe for Yammer OAuth integration. I don't see Yammer support in the examples folder. Is it planned in the near future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this isn't the best place to ask it but yes, [Yammer is supported out of the box](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/builder/api/YammerApi.java).

There is no example yet though :( but isn't this a great time to contribute one :) ?